# SWFObject fails to embed flash in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, swfobject

Been trying 4 hours to solve this out.
I've a really strange problem: SWFObject embeds flash good in all browsers except IE.
I printed the HTML of each outputted div into a textarea, and found out that in IE, SWFObject embeds the root "object" tag only, without any inner tags (such a param name="movie" value="myVal"), so I guess this is why I get "movie not loaded" in IE.

My code as follows:

```
window.embedFlash=function (properties)
{
    swfobject.addDomLoadEvent(function ()
    {
        swfobject.createSWF(
        {
            data: properties.data,
            width: properties.width||'100%',
            height: properties.height||'100%'
        },
        {
            allowScriptAccess: 'always',
            allowFullScreen: 'true',
            allowNetworking: properties.allowNetworking||'all',
            flashvars: properties.flashvars||null,
            wmode: properties.wmode||null,
            menu: properties.menu||'false'
        },properties.id);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually "movie not loaded" means Flash Player AVM instance has started, but the URL you provided can't be found.
Also, your SWF version may be out of sync with the Flash Player version in IE.

Check if you get any 404s and check if the compiled SWF version is runnable in the FP version installed to IE.

Comment: It happens on every computer I tried with latest flash version, so it's not that. Moreover, it works flawlessly in other browsers. I'm not getting 404s BUT I do use relative paths (resources/flash/myFile.swf) instead of 'http://www.mydomain.com/resources/flash/myFile.swf'. Yet, providing the full path doesnt help either.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically recreating the `swfobject.embedSWF` method, so I suggest reformatting your code to use `swfobject.embedSWF`, as it is widely supported and heavily tested. The only differences I see between your code and `embedSWF` are:

- lack of version detection in your
  code (embedSWF requires you to
  specify a minimum version of Flash
  Player
- lack of expressinstall in your
  code (this can be set to false in
  embedSWF if you're not interested
- your flashvars variable is probably 
  formatted as a string, whereas embedSWF 
  expects an object containing key/value pairs
- `swfobject.embedSWF` gets invoked on domload by default, so you wouldn't need to write an ondomload handler

Here's a quickie reformat of your code. It will fail if your flashvars are sent as a string:

```
window.embedFlash=function (properties)
{

    var flashvars = properties.flashvars||false;
    var params = {
       allowFullScreen: 'true',
       allowNetworking: properties.allowNetworking||'all',
       allowScriptAccess: 'always',
       menu: properties.menu||'false',
       wmode: properties.wmode||"window"
    };
    var attributes = {};

    swfobject.embedSWF(properties.data, 
                       properties.id, 
                       properties.width||'100%', 
                       properties.height||'100%', 
                       "9", 
                       false,//URL for expressinstall, if available 
                       flashvars, 
                       params, 
                       attributes);

};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet, the code you've provided doesn't work on IE either. Although now I get "Message: Unexpected call to method or property access." when calling swfobject.embedSWF.

Comment: Solved it! swfobject.js was corrupted once packed! original JS file works like a charm! thanks again all!

Comment: @GeverGever .... Holy cr*p, worked for me too. Looks like min version breaks params. In my case i've passed function string to flashVars and it corrupted double quotes. Happened only in ie.